# How to refactor this imperative JS to be functional?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, ramda.js

I tried all night and could not solve this puzzle.
The code, I want to refactor in functional way:

```
const R = require('ramda')
const axios = require('axios')
const Datastore = require('nedb')

const getDatastore = R.always(
  new Datastore({ filename: './cache.nedb', autoload: true }),
)

const writeHtmlToCache = R.curry((db, url, html) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.insert({ url, html }, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(doc)
    })
  })
})

const readHtmlFromCache = R.curry((db, url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.findOne({ url }, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(doc)
    })
  })
})

const app = async url => {
  const db = getDatastore()
  let html = R.prop('html', await readHtmlFromCache(db, url))
  if (html) {
    console.log('loaded from cache', html.length)
    return html
  } else {
    html = R.prop('data', await axios.get(url))
    writeHtmlToCache(db, url, html)
    console.log('loaded from web', html.length)
    return html
  }
}

app('http://example.org/')
```

Problems, that I encountered:
1) In `writeToCache` function I need `url` AND `html` as input to write record to db, but if I put this function in the pipe after `fetchHtml`, I got only `html`. And more - functions in pipe should be unary. Should I somehow make object `{ url: 'http...', html: '<html>...' }` before passing that in my `writeToCahce`?

2) I wanted to use R.either function to be able to `readFromCache` OR if no success there, go to my fetch from web pipe (which will save html in db too). But my cache reading function returns Promise. I could use `R.pipeP` but it seems not working with `either` (`R.either` continues with first function and returns null. Seems like it tests Promise itself and as it is truthy value, it gives my promise to pipeP and it resolves there as null (cache is empty) )

3) I tried to play with Task monad but with not big success. I am still new to these concepts

I feel like I did something completely wrong. Very curious how it can be done

Comment: If this is a working code, you might rather ask your question on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: wow didnt know about that resource. Can I transfer, or need to copypaste?

Comment: You should rather register there, and repost your question

Comment: Don't forget to `await` the `writeHtmlToCache(db, url, html)` call.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use some helpers from [crocks](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks) along with the magic of closures

```
import unless from 'crocks/logic/unless'
import composeP from 'crocks/combinators/composeP'

const getDataWithUrl = url => () =>
  axios.get(url).then(R.prop('data')))

const writeWithDbAndUrl = (db, url) => html =>
  writeHtmlToCache(db, url, html)

const writeWhenNoHtml = (db, url) =>
  composeP(writeWithDbAndUrl(db, url), getDataWithUrl(url))

const app = url => {
  const db = getDatastore()
  return readHtmlFromCache(db, url)
    .then(unless(R.prop('html'), writeWhenNoHtml(db, url))
}
```

Comment: Tried, works. But what about point-free'ness? Can we somehow improve it more to not mention parameters at all, or I am asking too much? :) Btw I am just learning and pointfree style is standard, as I got it from books/articles

Comment: @outluch "*pointfree style is standard*" - not at all. Make it point-free where you easily can, but where you can't (and have to ask how to use advanced combinators) then passing values around explicitly is much more maintainable. Point-free usually breaks down as soon as you need to use a value multiple times.

Comment: maybe mention `util.promisify` to prevent OP from creating `new Promise` wrappers around every db function

Comment: @outluch, @Bergi, I agree that pointfree style is generally desirable, but in these cases, where we specifically need to create closures to snag references, better not. You can see though in `writeWhenNoHtml` that we use *both* pointfree and pointfull styles in one function.

Comment: @user633183 can I see an example of what you mean? I've usually used `util.promisify` to wrap functions that take callbacks, but haven't used it to wrap functions that take a reference to a resource like `db`.

Comment: Ok. Got it: we can try pointfree in pure data processing scenarious (get response, get data prop, map somehow, reduce etc. But when it comes to more complex actions, nothing wrong with arguments etc.